# PHP Discord Webhook POST Request returns string(0)

Tags: php, curl, discord, webhooks

I am trying to post a discord message using webhooks, but every time I run the PHP file I get an error 'string(0) ""'.
I tried multiple things to fix it. Including these:

- Disabling SSL
- Different Webhook URLS

The PHP code is this:

````
//=======================================================================================================
// Create new webhook in your Discord channel settings and copy&paste URL
//=======================================================================================================

$webhookurl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/ REDACTED";


$timestamp = date("c", strtotime("now"));

$json_data = json_encode([
    // Message
    "content" => "Hello World!",

], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );


$ch = curl_init( $webhookurl );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
echo "Body -> ";
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
var_dump($body);
curl_close($ch);
?>```

(Yes I do have curl installed on the webserver.)
Any help would be appreciated.
````

Comment: Omit `Content-Length`. That can bring various problems.

Comment: Changed the line to ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));```. Still not working

Comment: Add some more info. What does [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error) say?

Comment: ```curl_error($ch);``` is blank when executed.

Comment: My bad** When executing the following code again I get ```Curl error: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error```;